# Unix Basic programming

Tags: unix

Can you explain why bash does not exit when you type Ctrl+C on the command line?
- Checked with the exit status on the terminal? 
- If exit status returns non-zero then it consider wrong commnd and returns non-zero value

Answer (score 1):

When you type Ctrl+C it sends an interrupt signal `SIGINT` to the process.  You can do the same thing with the `kill -2 <process-id>` command.

In the case of an interactive bash shell it catches `SIGINT` and handles it by breaking out of any executing loops.  You can read more about it [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html)

You can add signal handlers to most scripts or programs.  The only signal that can't be ignored is the `SIGKILL` (9) signal.  That will always stop a process.  That's why you can always kill something with kill -9 .

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **trap** syntax to take care of these signals. For example catching Ctrl+C and cleaning up before exit you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function cleanup {
    # cleanup whatever needed
    echo "cleanup"
    exit
}

trap cleanup SIGINT 

while true; do
    echo "Working"
    sleep 10
done

exit
```